# When would one write "con[struction]"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, quotations

A quote in a book contained the word "con[struction]."

It was used just as the word *construct* would have been. Is *con* ever used as an abbreviation of *construction*? Would there be any other reason to complete the quote like that?

Unfortunately I can't quote the context; I lost the bookmark, I don't remember the page, and I lack a searchable copy. I do remember that the quote was not weird in any other way, and that there was no apparent reason to do this. The book in question is Neal Stephenson's *Cryptonomicon*. The word might have been "con[truct]".

Comment: Both *construct* and *construction* have several meanings. Without context, I can do no more than sum up what the dictionaries give as possible senses. Perhaps it would help if you defined your notion of *construct* (you say "It was used just as the word construct would have been"). I understand it is difficult to explain something you're not sure about yourself! But I think some extra information could be added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Stephenson is just making a little joke. The full sentence is

**The boundary between Self and Environment is a social con[struct].**

By using the word *construct* he's asserting that this boundary isn't 'real', in that it's created by social conventions. But separating off the *con* part allows him to simultaneously assert that it's a 'deceitful trick' which by implication we're to understand we won't fall for after we've read and inwardly digested the wise words in his book.

**Update** Apparently my somewhat supercilious tone above is unjustified. The sentence appears in the novel as reported speech by Charlene, a character who appears to have some pretty odd ideas about the nature of society. Specifically at this point in the book she's asserting that all men would be clean-shaven if it weren't for the social pressure to be hirsute. It looks like Stephenson places these words in her mouth in order to poke fun at *her* attitudes.

Comment: Ah! A social construct, that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Fumble, that makes sense. Out of curiosity: how did you find the sentence?

Comment: @Tim: I hesitate to say where I got it... I just googled the author & title, noticed a pdf file in the first page of results, and downloaded it. In retrospect I now realise I'm probably in breach of copyright. But Hey! - I doubt I'll read the whole thing, so no lost sale there. And maybe some others *will* buy it after seeing this topic (sailing *really* close to the wind, you might try including *swordplay* in search terms).